# Grapple hooking with LineForces in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

I am making a grappling hook for a game about grappling through floating islands while collecting treasure, and recently I've been playing around with constraints and forces (vector forces, line forces, spring / rope constraints, etc.,). Anyways, I tried adapting a script to use line forces instead of rope constraints, but it is not working. There are no errors, so I am *very* confused.

I tried using this code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local HumanoidRootPart = player.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local debounce = false
local mouseDown = false

local MaxDistance = 300
local Magnitude = 10000
local RopeVisible = true
local RopeColor = BrickColor.new("Cocoa")

local function distance_between_vectors(u, v)
    local difference = u - v
    local distance = difference.Magnitude
    
    distance = math.floor(distance / 1 + 0.5) * 1
    return distance
end

local function Attachment(method, parent)
    if method == "Create" then
        local Attachment = Instance.new("Attachment")
        Attachment.Parent = parent
    else
        parent.Attachment:Destroy()
    end
end

mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = false
end)

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = true
    if debounce == false then
        debounce = true
        local hitPosition = mouse.Hit.Position
        local distance = distance_between_vectors(hitPosition, HumanoidRootPart.Position)
        if distance <= MaxDistance then
            local newPart = Instance.new("Part")
            newPart.Anchored = true
            newPart.Parent = game.Workspace
            newPart.Position = hitPosition
            newPart.Transparency = 0
            Attachment("Create", newPart)
            Attachment("Create", HumanoidRootPart)
            local Rope = Instance.new("LineForce")
            Rope.Parent = newPart
            Rope.Attachment0 = newPart.Attachment
            Rope.Attachment1 = HumanoidRootPart.Attachment
            Rope.Magnitude = Magnitude
            Rope.Visible = RopeVisible
            Rope.Color = RopeColor
            Rope.MaxForce = 1000
            while mouseDown == true do
                wait()
            end
            Attachment("Destroy", newPart)
            Attachment("Destroy", HumanoidRootPart)
            newPart.LineForce:Destroy()
            newPart:Destroy()
        end
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```

This, for some reason, refuses to work. Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Programming_Good_Games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that a rod constraint was the way to go. Sorry to anyone who was going to try to help. I'll put the script so that anyone that needs it can use it:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local HumanoidRootPart = player.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local debounce = false
local mouseDown = false

local MaxDistance = 500
local RopeVisible = true
local RopeColor = BrickColor.new("Cocoa")

local function distance_between_vectors(u, v)
    local difference = u - v
    local distance = difference.Magnitude
    
    distance = math.floor(distance / 1 + 0.5) * 1
    return distance
end

local function Attachment(method, parent)
    if method == "Create" then
        local Attachment = Instance.new("Attachment")
        Attachment.Parent = parent
    else
        if parent:FindFirstChild("Attachment") then
            parent.Attachment:Destroy()
        end
    end
end

mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = false
end)

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    mouseDown = true
    if debounce == false then
        debounce = true
        local hitPosition = mouse.Hit.Position
        local distance = distance_between_vectors(hitPosition, HumanoidRootPart.Position)
        if distance <= MaxDistance then
            local newPart = Instance.new("Part")
            newPart.Anchored = true
            newPart.Parent = game.Workspace
            newPart.Position = hitPosition
            newPart.Transparency = 1
            newPart.CanCollide = false
            Attachment("Create", newPart)
            Attachment("Create", HumanoidRootPart)
            local Rope = Instance.new("RodConstraint")
            Rope.Parent = newPart
            Rope.Attachment0 = newPart.Attachment
            Rope.Attachment1 = HumanoidRootPart.Attachment
            Rope.Color = RopeColor
            Rope.Length = distance
            Rope.Visible = RopeVisible
            Rope.Thickness = 0.25
            local tween = game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(Rope, TweenInfo.new(0.6, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 0, false), {Length = 0})
            tween:Play()
            newPart.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
                if touched then
                    if touched == HumanoidRootPart then
                        wait(0.1)
                        Attachment("Destroy", newPart)
                        Attachment("Destroy", HumanoidRootPart)
                        newPart.RodConstraint:Destroy()
                        newPart:Destroy()
                    else
                        wait()
                    end
                end
            end)
        end
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```

Hope this helps,
Programming_Good_Games